# Confusion regarding latent heat of fusion

Tags: thermodynamics

During vaporizing there is higher increase in internal energy (higher positive $\Delta U$) and more work is done by the liquid (higher $W$) as molecules become widely separated.

During melting, there is small increase in internal energy (smaller positive $\Delta U$) and less work is done by the solid (smaller $W$) as there is less difference in the molecule separation relatively.

According to $Q=\Delta U - W$, why is the specific latent heat of vaporization greater than that of fusion? In both cases $Q$ works out to be same according to above statements?

Comment: Are you essentially asking why is $ L_{v} > L_{f} $ . what does
"sine more minus more = less and less minus lesss = less?" mean . can you clarify ?

Comment: Improved the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was simply confused by the sign convention in the first law of thermodynamics.

The most convenient way to write it is $Q=\Delta U + W$  where $W$ is the work done by the system.

Hence the answer to my question becomes clear after this.

Answer (score 1):

Let me clear a few things up first; the latent heat of fusion is the energy required to convert a substance from solid form to a liquid form. Since water is liquid at room temperature, the latent heat of fusion is positive as energy is *absorbed* to convert ice to water, just as energy is *released* when water  is converted to ice.  It sounds counter-intuitive, I know, but *release* could also mean 'sucked away', which is exactly what is done in a freezer.

Now, molecules close together in solids, a little less close together in liquids, and extremely far apart in gases. There is a lot of [cohesion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohesion_(chemistry)) in both ice and liquid water, however very little in water vapor. The great difference in energy required to melt ice and to form water vapor is because a lot of energy is required to overcome cohesion.

This cohesion occurs because of the polarity of water molecules. [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PVL24HAesnc) should help you out!

Comment: I know it is greater but the thermodynamic law equation confused me and you havnt answered in terms of that

Answer (score 0):

It should be (delta)U=q+-w, where +- means plus or minus, like the sign used in the quadratic formula.
The sign for w should be determine by the type of work done, ie. compression (+w) or expansion work (-w).